# Get the current value of UISlider in drawRect: method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uislider, uibezierpath

I'm trying to move a point drawn in a UIView based on the value of a UISlider. The code below is for a UIView (subview ?) with a custom class (WindowView) on a UIViewController.

**WindowView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WindowView : UIView

- (IBAction)sliderValue:(UISlider *)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *windowLabel;


@end
```

**WindowView.m**

```
#import "WindowView.h"

@interface WindowView ()
{
    float myVal; // I thought my solution was using an iVar but I think I am wrong
}

@end

@implementation WindowView

@synthesize windowLabel;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)sliderValue:(UISlider *)sender
{
    myVal = sender.value;
    windowLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", myVal];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // I need to get the current value of the slider in drawRect: and update the position of the circle as the slider moves
    UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(myVal, myVal, 10, 10)];
    [circle fill];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you need to store the slider value in an instance variable and then force the view to redraw.

WindowView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WindowView : UIView
{
    float _sliderValue;   // Current value of the slider
}

// This should be called sliderValueChanged
- (IBAction)sliderValue:(UISlider *)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *windowLabel;
@end
```

WindowView.m (modified methods only):

```
// This should be called sliderValueChanged
- (void)sliderValue:(UISlider *)sender
{
    _sliderValue = sender.value;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];   // Force redraw
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(_sliderValue, _sliderValue, 10, 10)];
    [circle fill];
}
```

You probably want to initialise `_sliderValue` to something useful in the view's init method.

Also `_sliderValue` probably isn't the name you want to choose; perhaps something like `_circleOffset` or some such.

Comment: Sweet! I knew it was something simple. Thanks a billion!